# check if value exist in another table before insert SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, cursor

I have table: " daysoff " and table: " rdv "

**the *rdv* table looks like this :**

| temps_rdv | etat_rdv | ID_RDV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12-10-2022 | reservee | 2 |

**the *daysoff* table looks like this :**

| ID | DATE_OFF | REASON |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 12-06-2023 | conge |

i want to insert values in rdv table, but before inserting any thing i need to check first if " temps_rdv " doesn't exist in the daysoff table

**example: I can not add a rdv with temps_rdv = 12-06-2023**

I tried a trigger, but it doesn't seem to work

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
BEFORE INSERT ON rdv
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (
            select daysoff.date_off
            From Available daysoff  -- CHANGED THE ALIAS TO A
            where (NEW.temps_rdv = daysoff.date_off)
        ) THEN 
           CALL:='Insert not allowed';

        END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary table, insert your values into the temporary table and then poupolate rdv form the temporary table using a not exists condition on the dayoff table.

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_rdv_insert(
  temps_rdv date,
  etat_rdv varchar(255),
  ID_RDV int
 );

INSERT INTO tmp_rdv_insert(temps_rdv, etat_rdv, ID_RDV)
VALUES (TO_DATE('2023-06-12','YYYY-MM-DD'), 'test', 5);

INSERT INTO rdv
select * from tmp_rdv_insert tmp
where not exists (select 1 from daysoff where DATE_OFF = tmp.temps_rdv);
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3906/6)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MERGE`. Then handle `WHEN NOT MATCHED` to insert or update. Triggers are a terrible way to approach this. Worse case scenario you end up with a mutating trigger and everything goes ka-boom. If you don't want to rely on SQL, you can use PL/SQL. If all else fails, you can use a transient table (for example a temporary table for the current session) to check the values you need (or don't need). Depending on what you want to achieve, I recommend you take a look at `MERGE` first. It might just be what you need.

Comment: like this : 


MERGE rdv AS TARGET
USING daysoff AS SOURCE
ON (TARGET.temps_rdv = SOURCE.date_off)
 WHEN MATCHED
         AND TARGET.temps_rdv <> SOURCE.date_off) 
    THEN print ('impossible');

Comment: Not quite. The syntax is incorrect. You combined `MERGE` with `WITH ... AS... SELECT`. You need to check the syntax on the Oracle site. Here are some explanations: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-merge/ . If `MERGE` is what you need, please mark my answer as **ACCEPTED**.

Comment: @TheNomad OP has provided table and sample data. Could you add the actual merge statement that you'd use in this case ?